# How to configure django-auth-adfs?

Tags: django, adfs, django-authentication

I'm using a demo project from https://github.com/jobec/django-auth-adfs/tree/master/demo/adfs
Here are my settings:

```
AUTH_ADFS = {
    "SERVER": "sso.example.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml",
    "CLIENT_ID": "******-****-****-****-********",
    "RESOURCE": "localhost:8000",
    "REDIR_URI": "localhost:8000/oauth2/login",
    "CA_BUNDLE": False,
    "CLAIM_MAPPING": {"first_name": "given_name",
                      "last_name":  "family_name",
                      "email":      "email"},
}
```

The program runs fine, but there is no way to enter the Admin panel or the user panel. By clicking on the link Admin or Login, without requesting a login and password, go to the page "Login failed".

I can not figure out where I wronged the app.

Answer (score 0):

There were inconsistencies in the settings of the ADFS, having gone all the way again https://github.com/jobec/django-auth-adfs/blob/master/docs/adfs_3.0_config_guide.rst all worked) Thank you to the developers!